# Don't lint keys in tuples

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tuples, eslint, typescript-eslint

I use tuples-pairs in my app to define ordered-data with (say) a label and a contents.  It's just easier for me to read than using an object like `{ label: string, contents: React.ReactNode }`.

This works fine, right up until linting.  Consider the following:

```
function FriendList(props: {friends: string[]}): React.ReactElement {
    return <div className="FriendList">{props.friends.join(", ")}</div>;
}


const appData: [string, React.ReactNode][] = [
    ["Birth year", (new Date(1608310316544).getFullYear()],
    ["Friends", <FriendList friends={["Fred", "Sally", "Mary"]} />],
];

function App(): React.ReactElement {
    return <div className="App">{
        appData.map((row, i) => <div className="App__row" key={i}>
            <div className="App__row__label">{row[0]}</div>
            <div className="App__row__content">{row[1]}</div>
        </div>)
    }</div>
}
```

Here, we define some data about some person and then want to display it.  For each row in our app we always have exactly one "label" and exactly one "contents".  The first row `"Birth year"` works fine - its contents is a string.  The second row - `"Friends"` has a linting error:

```
Missing "key" prop for element in array eslint(react/jsx-key)
```

Technically this is correct.  I am defining a React element inside a collection - but there is no need for keys, the tuple is not *rendered* as a collection.  The number of siblings of each element in the tuple will never change, and their syntax is tightly controlled by the renderer.

I imagine this is the case for most tuples (it certainly is for all of mine).  I like the `react/jsx-key` rule - I'd like to keep it, but I also don't want to manually disable it for every line with an element in a Tuple.

**Is there any way to disable this rule for tuples?**  Or perhaps conditionally in some way?

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I think that's a bug in eslint-react and you should maybe report the same at
https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react.

You can of course just do [`// eslint-disable-next-line react/jsx-key`](https://eslint.org/docs/2.13.1/user-guide/configuring#disabling-rules-with-inline-comments) for the time being...

Comment: It occurred to me that this would have to be in the `typescript-eslint` rule-set though since the JS one would have no way to know that something's a tuple.  I think it's fair to ask for a key on every element in an array, even statically defined ones.